# Scraping portions of text only after specific words in HTML file

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm very new to Python (one week old), so I'm sorry if this sounds silly but and I would really appreciate some help. I want to scape specific portions of text in an HTML file. For example, let's say the whole text is :

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
> Nunc fringilla arcu congue metus aliquam mollis.
> Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus.
> Quisque at dignissim lacus.

I want to scape the all text after the word "mollis" and before the word "Quisque at dignissim lacus" and the desirable output should be :

> Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus.

So far, I have just managed to scrape some parts from a website and remove the HTML tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from re import findall

file = open('filename.html', encoding= "UTF-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'lxml')

for match in soup.find_all('div', class_='discussion-desc'):
    recom = match.text

re.findall(r'@(\w+)','recommendations')
#['recommendations', 'steps']
#re.findall(r'@(\w+)', 'recommendations')
#[]
#(re.findall(r'@(\w+)', 'recommendations') or None,)[0]
#'recommendations'
#print (re.findall(r'@(\w+)', 'recommendations') or None,)[0]
#None
```

Please help, thank you.

Comment: *remove the HTML tag* ? -  What do you mean by this ? You have ```beautifulsoup``` to get the contents between the tags.

Comment: I mean remove all the <div> </div> <head> </head> (i don't know what thats called) and extract just the readable text.

Answer (score 0):

In case of single occurance, you can use: `re.search()` :

```
s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc fringilla arcu congue metus aliquam mollis. Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus. Quisque at dignissim lacus"

re.search(r'mollis\.(.*?)Quisque at dignissim lacus', s).group(1)
```

Output:

```
Out[28]: ' Mauris nec maximus purus. Maecenas sit amet pretium tellus. '
```

In case of multiple occurances, have a look at  `re.findall()`